# How to show different views when switching tabs in android?

Tags: android, layout, swipe

I am developing a facebook kind of app, I have selected swipe views while creating new android project in android studio. I get the same layout page in every section as i swipe. How to show different layouts for different screens?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). Read abouit it and you'll see that they are very useful.

Here you have a very good [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) for designing different UIs for different screen sizes using [`Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) and [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

And [Google Play Style Tabs using TabLayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout) may help you.